# Increment for loop pointer in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, coffeescript

```
for char, index in 'some string'
    if condition
        index += 2
```

I have a for loop, where I'm looping over a string and when certain condition is met, I want to skip some number of characters after the current one. In JavaScript, I would do `index += 2` and it would work, but for some unknown reason, CoffeeScript compiler compiles this code into JS `for` loop, that uses `_i` variable to keep the real index and only assigns the current value to `index`, which means that by changing the value of `index`, I'm not really changing the pointer.

I know I could do this using `while` loop, but I just keep thinking that there must be a way to do this using `for` loop. Am I right, or should I just stick to the `while` loop?

Here is the compiled JS code:

```
var char, index, _i, _len, _ref;

_ref = 'some string';
for (index = _i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; index = ++_i) {
  char = _ref[index];
  if (condition) {
    index += 2;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at: [CoffeeScript for loop get iterator var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388209/coffeescript-for-loop-get-iterator-var)

You can't change the real index of a `for` loop in CoffeeScript, AFAIK. You'd have to use a `while` loop instead.